# Iphone View Crul left right

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

IPhone SDK has UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp/Down
I want Curl left-right like a reading a book.
Is any way to do this without Landscape Orientation.

Thanks
Amit Battan

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a transform on the view, for example, a 90° rotation. Then, when the curl animates, it should respect that transform. Of course, you'll need to UNtransform your content, so this can get a little complicated.